# DevOps Board User Story Card: Test Icon does not display after link created to user story

Tags: user-story

Preview Issue that was reported & not fixed & closed:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tests-are-not-showing-on-board-card-unless-created/696589

The board for User Story card will not display the Test beker icon when a test case is created and link is created (via Add Link). The test icon will only display on the user story card after user clicks the ellipsis then clicks the + Add Test and then the user story card refreshes and the test icon is displayed. This is a huge issue as the team is unable to see the associated tests on the user story card and the work around for the user story card to be refreshed requires a dummy test case to be created. Then an additional process of having to delete the dummy test is required. What is the Fix for this?